# Etched border (Win32)

Tags: winapi, border

I'm looking for a way to get an etched border style for a window under win32. I have tried `DrawEdge` with the `EDGE_ETCHED` flag, which does give me that, but I'm not sure how obtain the same style for a scrollable window. `SetWindowLong` with `GWL_EXSTYLE` and `WS_EX_STATICEDGE` gives me something close, but I haven't found any other style flags that yield a different border. So is this effect even possible?

Thanks in advance,
Christopher

Comment: Erm, what does WS_VSCROLL have to do with the border style?  Set the style flags in CreateWindowEx(), its a crap shoot after that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed out that I'm actually calling win32/GDI stuff from LispWorks CAPI, the Common Lisp GUI tool-kit - so I don't create the windows myself. I've been using DrawEdge to draw an etched border, but anything drawn that way eventually gets scrolled off in a CAPI scrolling window.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that sort of thing by handling `WM_NCPAINT` and other `WM_NCxxx` messages.

The `NC` stands for "Non Client area" of the window.  The normal drawable area returned in the Device Context (DC) from `BeginPaint` is clipped to the "client area" of the window.